# astropy.match_coordinates_sky confusion

Tags: python, astropy

I am working on a code to match two catalogs of RA and declination values. I have read these into two different `SkyCoord` objects called `scatalog` (length ~ 30,000) and `pcatalog` (length ~ 500,000).

The `pcatalog` is bigger, so I want to match the targets in `scatalog` into `pcatalog`.

When I do

```
idx, d2d, d3d = match_coordinates_sky(scatalog, pcatalog, nthneighbor=1)
```

I am confused by the results.

The documentation [on astropy](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.coordinates.match_coordinates_sky.html) indicates that the shape of `idx` should match the shape of `scatalog.` Instead, it has the same length as `pcatalog`. Does anyone know why that would happen?

Also, the documentation says that `idx` are the indices into `pcatalog` which are the closest matches to the entries of `scatalog`. That would make since if my other problem weren't happening. However, if `idx` has the length as `pcatalog`, then there is duplication in the matches. How do get it to return the index of just the closest match?

**What does it mean for the values of `idx` to not be unique?**

I would appreciate any help you wonderful people could provide!

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem: I've provided an answer as an example, but more information is needed to found out what the actual problem is. Preferably through a [mcve], though that may be impossible with the catalogs you are using. Perhaps you can use a very minimal subsection of the two catalogs to reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Note: this is not an answer, but an example to show that I can't reproduce the problem. More information is needed to verify and help with the problem.

```
import numpy as np
from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord, match_coordinates_sky
from astropy import units as u

scatalog = SkyCoord(ra=np.linspace(0, 1, 10)*u.degree, dec=np.ones(10)*u.degree)
pcatalog = SkyCoord(ra=np.linspace(0, 1, 100)*u.degree, dec=np.ones(100)*u.degree)
idx, d2d, d3d = match_coordinates_sky(scatalog, pcatalog, nthneighbor=1)
print(idx.shape)
print(d2d.shape)
```

yields

```
(10,) (100,)
(10,) (10,)
```

that is, `idx` and `d2d` have the same shape as `scatalog`, not as `pcatalog`.